# Barra de stilos y formato de texto en QTextEdit

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

Me planteo en añadir una barra de estilos de texto (Tamaño de letra, tipo de letra, negrita, cursiva, subrayado ...) en una ventana que contiene un QtextEdit.

Por lo que veo, tendría que programarla desde cero a no ser que en el QtDesigner exista alguna característica de QtextEdit.

Existe alguna forma de añadir la barra de formato de texto fácilmente? o tendría que programarla manualmente?

Gracias de antemano, estoy buscando ideas por si lo añadiera finalmente.

Comment: Hay un ejemplo de Qt que hace lo que deseas, puedes revisarlo en el siguiente enlace: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-textedit-example.html

Comment: Gracias!! no lo encontré antes :)

Comment: QtCreator tiene un monton de ejemplos, revisalos, muchas cosas de las que deseas hacer ya estan hechas. ademas si quieres ver más código de Qt puedes revisar mi repo: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow :-)

Comment: muchísimas gracias voy a revisar tu repo, por eso pregunte...antes de hacerlo de nuevo por si ya existía algo. Gracias :D